# Matlab creates permissionless files

Tags: matlab, random, file-permissions, nas

I have a script in MATLAB that outputs various files, including NIFTI (MRI images) files and text log files. Sometimes the output files that are created have their file permissions set to no read or write for anyone, including the file owner, and this appears to occur randomly.

This normally isn't a problem unless it occurs with the logs, as it leads MATLAB to endlessly recurse as it tries to write the error to the logs. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find anyone who has experienced similar behavior from any program, including MATLAB.

The script, input files, and output files are all located on a NAS drive connected to a server running Ubuntu 14.04, so I'm wondering if this is a problem with the script (probably not because it happens intermittently regardless of input), the matlab environment, or the NAS drive.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why yoru fileattributes/permissions are changing, but I know the solution. You want [file attributes](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fileattrib.html) if you know [chmod](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod) from unix this should be familiar, if not you will still be fine

something like this will make your files **w**riteable for **a**ll user groups on a unix (ubuntu) system

```
fileattrib('/home/work/results/my_file.log','+w','a')
```

**edit**

since these files are non-existant this may work better. Simply use fopen with the 'w+' flag. Which means write mode for appending. The + will also create the file if it doesn't exist(and you have permission to create files in the specified directory)

```
fid = fopen('my_new_log.txt','w+');
fprintf(fid,'some strings for my file');
fclose(fid);
```

it is also important you make sure to close the file after you are done.

Comment: Wouldn't that just change the attributes for a file or files that already exist? I need to prevent this behavior from occuring, as it causes Matlab to stop the script and throw an error.

Comment: I see now. I thought you modified a file in matlab and then AFTER modifying it the permissions were different. Try posting some of your code (perhaps where you create and close the files) there may be something else at play. Maybe there is an error in writing/closing the files so it leaves the permissions in a weird state, but Id need to see more to know for sure

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think I can post the code. The script is part of another lab's pipeline; both the size and permission restrictions would make it difficult.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'll add that and see if it addresses the issue